# Как увеличить точность класса float

Tags: python

Насколько я знаю, точность типа `float` в `python` ограничена 16 знаками после запятой. Мне необходимо около 40 знаков после запятой. И вот вопрос, как увеличить количество знаков после запятой в типе `float`, или какой типа данных использовать вместо флоат, для которого определены операции с комплексными числами?

Answer (score 2):

[Проект GMPY](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) не устроит? Биндинги к gmp и mpfr.

Comment: интересная штука, где можно подробнее почитать и как я понимаю документации на русском нет?

Comment: Ну на сам пакет доки на английском и очень короткие, на библиотеку gmp и другие (mpfr, mpri) тоже на аглицком, но что-нибудь вкратце на русском возможно где-то и есть. В составе пакетов есть тесты. Они не столько на английском, сколько на питоне.

Comment: как библиотеку подключить к питону? она на си написана, простой импорт не работает. и вообще проект староват - последние изменения к 2006 году относятся.

Comment: Честно говоря, откуда цифра 2006 -- непонятно. gmpy2-2.0.0a2 -- 8 июня, gmpy-1.14 -- ноябрь 2010. Виндовые бинарники должны подключаться сами (надеюсь), а под линухом -- `sudo python setup.py install`. Только про основные библиотеки (gmplib или другие) забывать не надо.

Comment: @eiyawii: [gmpy2](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html) поддерживает MPFR  (float) and MPC (complex) библиотеки. [Самое последнее изменение от 8 марта 2015 (меньше месяца назад)](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/source/list)

Answer (score 2):

Также могу посоветовать пакет [mpmath](http://mpmath.org); 
[Numpy](http://numpy.org) поддерживает float128, но это около 32 знаков.
А вообще, вопрос с точностью очень актуальный, существует весьма простой [пример вычислений с плавающей точкой (на Python)](http://easydan.com/arts/2016/pyfloats-comp/), заставляющий задуматься, что верить расчетам с плавающей точкой нужно очень осторожно...

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, для более точных расчетов в Python используют класс Decimal. Подробнее о нем  можно прочитать [здесь](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) В этом классе можно управлять точностью вычислений, потерь значений в нем не происходит, в отличии от double, но при этом, конечно, ждать высокую скорость работы не стоит.

Comment: дело в том, что Decimal не дружит ни с float, ни с complex. а так конечно идеально подходит, я тестовую проблему напишу и выложу, чтобы показать где ошибка возникает. также рассматривал тип Fraction, и надо сказать он подошел, все операции с этим типом проходят, кроме вычисления логарифма - если аргумент функции log10 является число типа Fraction, то возбуждается исключение

Comment: Потери в Decimal также происходят -- разница в том, что база десятичная (а не в двоичная) и точность можно свою выставить (а не фиксированная (для данной платформы, компилятора).  А так близкие стандарты, относящиеся к арифметике с плавающей точкой используются.

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, но придется их эмулировать самостоятельно. Дело в том, что по умолчанию в питоне используется тип Double, который имеет размер 8 байт, 52 бита из них используется для мантиссы, которые как раз и дают 15-16 знаков в десятичном виде. Что бы обеспечить 40 знаков после запятой, нужно где то 132 бита только для мантиссы. И ещё бит 12-15 для экспоненты. Итого 144-147 бит (18-19 байт). Мне не известны библиотеки, которые оперируют такими числами.

Если уточните задачу, зачем нужна такая точность, может быть подкину красивое решение проблемы. Но в обычных задачах оно очень редко нужно. В своей жизни только один раз встречал задачу, в которой нужна была точность 12 знаков после запятой, и то, как потом оказалось, это была синтетическая задача, что бы отсечь тех, кто пользуется калькулятором и не умеет думать.

Comment: А если калькулятор даёт точность больше 12 знаков?
Прошу прощения за оффтоп.

А по сути вопроса - почитайте про длинную арифетику.

Comment: большинство калькуляторов как раз имеют точность 10-12 знаков. (я о калькуляторах физических, а не тех, что в операционных системах).

Comment: а что скажите по поводу Decimal, Fraction? Оба типа могут представить число достаточно точно. Но попробовав использовать эти типы, я столкнулся с проблемами - Decimal не дружит с float и complex, а Fraction не может быть аргументом таких функций как log10. Хотел бы сказать, что задача стоит тоже синтетическая, но необходимая для наглядности. Я попозже напишу тестовую проблему, в которой возникают ошибки при применении этих типов и выложу здесь.

Comment: Ну, если загвоздка только в логарифме, то его можно и сосчитать с нужной точностью. Формулы можно подглядеть в учебнике по алгебре или [тут](http://www.mobilab.ru/articles/99/).